# Access to Azure Management Portal in C#

Tags: c#, rest, azure, mvvm, active-directory

I am trying to create a cross-platform app that allows a user to login to Azure Management Portal using his Live ID and manage his services. I know that the REST API can be used to access the Management portal.

But I am not sure how to implement the authentication part of it. I have gathered that to authenticate, the user has to upload a X.509 certificate for every request (if it is done by REST) or he has give info like subscription id, domain name etc. and also create a new application in the Active Directory of the Management portal using ADAL library.

But the user isn't expected to do this. Is there anyway to access the Management portal using ONLY the Live ID and password the user provides. Another dilemma I have is whether authentication can be implemented in a portable class library. The required classes for X.509 certificate are not accessible in a PCL. So, does authentication need to implemented for every platform separately?